# Sklearn accuracy score of user input with two lists Python (always 0%)

Tags: python

I have two lists with two types of values (int values are in list called projekti and string values are in vreme).
I want to make a program, that will predict the string value based on user input. User input is int value. I also want to check the accuracy of prediction.
The program gives me an error, and also always gives me the accuracy of 0%, no matter whats the user input.
What am I doing wrong?

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

projekti=[[1000], [1300], [1400], [1100], [1200], [1100], [1500]] #velicina objekta, broj nivoa, vreme

vreme=[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] #uspesnost vremena

clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf=clf.fit(projekti,vreme)

unos=input("unesi velicinu: ")
List1=[]

List1.append([unos])

prediction=clf.predict(List1)

accuracy=accuracy_score(List1, prediction)
print(prediction[0]," ", accuracy*100,"%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `prediction` is output as a single element list of either `["no"]` or `["yes"]`, therefore when you call `accuracy = accuracy_score(List1, prediction)`, you are comparing a list containing a string value (`str`) with an integer value (`int`), which will always be 0.

This works for me:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

projekti = [1000, 1300, 1400, 1100, 1200, 1100, 900]
vreme = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit([[i] for i in projekti],vreme)

valuetotest = [900]
expectedresult = 0

prediction = clf.predict([valuetotest])
print(prediction)

accuracy=accuracy_score([expectedresult], prediction)
print(accuracy*100," %")
```

Gives:

```
[0]
100.0  %
```

To test multiple data points:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np

projekti = [1000, 1300, 1400, 1100, 1200, 1100, 900]
vreme = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit([[i] for i in projekti],vreme)

valuetotest = [900, 1100, 1500, 2200]
expectedresult = [0, 1, 0, 0]

prediction = clf.predict([[i] for i in valuetotest])
print(prediction)

accuracy=accuracy_score([[i] for i in expectedresult], prediction)
print(accuracy*100," %")
```

Gives:

```
[0 1 0 0]
100.0  %
```

Comment: Ok, but If say (for example) that yes=1 and no=0, and I put in list called `vreme`, a program is going to give me correct values, right?

I mean, if this works , can I use the program for some realistic (acurate) predictions?

Comment: Well with the amount of data you have included above you will likely get poor results, however a larger training set should improve the accuracy of your predictions. I would consider assembling a large set of training data and then using 75% of that data (at random) to train your classifier and then use the remaining 25% as your test set. Using 1's and 0's would be a sufficient replacement for 'yes' and 'no'.

Comment: I updated the question, now program gives me error, and also always the accuracy of 0%

Comment: See my updated answer. In your updated post, you are still attempting to compare an input feature to an output...

Comment: The syntax appears odd because you are only supplying a feature matrix that contains a single feature for each training example, therefore you have to group individual elements into their own lists. If you had multiple features for a given training example, then each entry in the list `projekti` would be a list containing the values of those features.

Comment: Oh, ok
yeah it works now. But I do not understand this part of code: `clf = clf.fit([[i] for i in projekti],vreme)` and  `expectedresult = 0`

and also, code always gives me 0% od 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166491/discussion-between-rahlf23-and-aleksandar-beat).